# How to pack images to DLL in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, resources

I have images in View/Images folder of my class library. I tried to set their Build action to Resources and Embedded Resources but they are not packed to class library dll. How can I do this?

Comment: In `WPF` you should set the build action to `Resource`

Comment: Ideally IMO build action for such cases should be Content. Especially Images. They get loaded faster as Content than as an embedded resource.

Answer (score 0):

As Reza mentioned,set the Build action to Embedded Resource for all the images.I have used the following code snippet to check whether the images are loaded into the DLL or not.I am able to get all the images

```
protected void btnGetImages_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Assembly currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string[] resources = currentAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
            foreach(string resource in resources)
            {
                Response.Write(resource + "<br/>");
            }
        }
```